# How to convert this d3 v3 graph to a v4?

Tags: d3.js

I have been trying to convert this example in d3 v3 to a v4 version but still having trouble.
http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

Here is a JSFiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/echilee/sfbcntph/135/

I am able to console.log the LINKS and the NODES.  I made some progress and am able to see the nodes and click to open and close those that are connected. But cannot see links and how they should connect the nodes.

I replaced the nodes and links declaration and force function with this code:

```
// create a hierarchy from the root
const treeRoot = hierarchy(root)
tree(treeRoot)
const nodes = flatten(treeRoot.descendants())
const links = treeRoot.links()
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
```

I am not able to see the links.

Comment: Are there nodes in the DOM when you open the inspector? Are there errors in the console? Try adding console.log statements

Comment: @RubenHelsloot   I added some console.logs and am able to log the links and the nodes. Just having trouble to display them.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot thank you in advance for your assistance. I have made some progress and am now able to see the nodes and click to close the ones that are connected. But cannot see the links to connect them. Here is my latest on JSFiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/echilee/sfbcntph/135/